# ERROR building one of the platforms: IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

Following ionic lessons about up and running mobile hybrid app I was stumbled at step:

```
$ ionic build ios
```

the following error is:

```
$ ionic build ios
Running command: "c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe##c:\wamp\www\weather\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_    class.js c:/wamp/www/weather
add to body class: platform-ios
Running command: cmd "/s/c"c:\wamp\www\weather\platforms\ios\cordova\build""
'c:\wamp\www\weather\platforms\ios\cordova\build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone        (c:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

I have no troubles with ionic build android.
Could You help me with some suggestions where the problem come from?
Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you use Windows.

> Note: iOS development requires Mac OS X.

Source: http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

If you really need to build for iOS, you will need to buy a Mac (yeah, this is really sad) or use a solution that handles this kind of case, like [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).
If I remember well, the Ionic team is working on a solution solving this, but it is not yet ready.

Comment: Tnx, that explanation for me is enough :)